# Is it safe to use capture pattern assignmens from match/case statements directly?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm using Python 3.10's `match` pattern matching syntax to transform some basic objects into a consistent structure. For this example let's say I'm trying to get a list of args and a dict of kwargs from objects that might have varying structures:

```
sample_args = [
    ['item1', 'item2', {'key': 'value'}],
    [['item1', 'item2'], {'key': 'value'}],
    ['item1', 'item2'],
    {'key': 'value'},
    ['item1']
]
```

I might do something like this:

```
normalise_args(fn_args):
    args = []
    kwargs = {}
    
    match fn_args:
        case [[*args], {**kwargs}]:
            args = args
            kwargs = kwargs
        case [*args, {**kwargs}]:
            args = args
            kwargs = kwargs
        case [*args]:
            args = args
        case {**kwargs}:
            kwargs = kwargs
        case _:
            args = [fn_args]

    return args, kwargs

for fn_args in sample_args:
    args, kwargs = normalise_args(fn_args)
    assert isinstance(args, list)
    assert isinstance(kwargs, dict)
```

Sure enough, that works. But as I understand it, the `case …` condition itself is binding variable names, so there's no actual work to be done in the case body. Therefore the following works exactly the same:

```
normalise_args(fn_args):
    args = []
    kwargs = {}
    
    match fn_args:
        case [[*args], {**kwargs}]:
            pass
        case [*args, {**kwargs}]:
            pass
        case [*args]:
            pass
        case {**kwargs}:
            pass
        case _:
            args = [fn_args]

    return args, kwargs
```

Here's my question: is there any reason not to use this second form? It seems to me that binding the variables is guaranteed either way. "Explicit is better than implicit" is a reasonable argument, but the first version isn't really doing anything except making redundant assignments anyway. I can't find any other side effects here, so I'm not sure.

Comment: `args = args` doesn't do anything, there's no reason to write that.

Comment: What you're doing in the second piece of code looks fine to me.